# Installing glib in non-standard prefix fails

Tags: makefile, installation, glib, libtool

I'm trying to install glib in a non-standard prefix but I get the following when running `make install`:

```
/bin/sh ../libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c libgthread-2.0.la '/root/build/lib'
libtool: install: error: cannot install `libgthread-2.0.la' to a directory not ending in /usr/local/lib
```

Any reason why I *have to* install gthread only in a prefix ending with /usr/local/lib?

Comment: Did you configure it right? I mean `./configure --prefix=<prefix_of_your_choice>` ? Try `make clean ; make distclean; ./configure --prefix=<prefix_of_your_choice> && make && make install`

Comment: I did all of that, to no avail. I finally did something like `../gcc-4.7.0/configure --prefix=/root/build/usr/local/` to make it work.

Comment: You definitely don't have to install glib only in /usr/local/lib; this is due to some libtool or automake weirdness, perhaps stale intermediate files lying around in the tree.  I would try untarring a fresh source package and starting from scratch.

Comment: That was a fresh source tree, right out of the tar archive. It doesn't say it has to be /usr/local/lib, it says it has to end with that, which is still weird.

Answer (score 73):

I also just stumbled over that problem when compiling MonetDB on my Linux machine. Here is the solution/workaround that worked for me: Always `make clean` after `./configure`.

In your example you should be able to do:

```
./configure --prefix=/root/build && make clean && make && make install
```

I found the solution in a [discussion](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35098) on an apache httpd bug where Joe Orton shares [his knowledge](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35098#c7):

> A "make clean" is usually necessary after re-running "configure".

Comment: I had this problem while compiling Gimp 2.9.2. `libtool:   error: error: cannot install 'libgimpcolor-2.0.la' to a directory not ending in /usr/local/lib`. The answer works, but isn't there another method instead of running `make clean`. A full build takes ~15 minutes, just because one library seems to somehow hardcode the prefix ...

Answer (score 1):

Using:

```
make clean 
make distclean
```

Works for me.

Answer (score -1):

The `install` path of a library can usually be customized rather than the default one under somewhere `/usr/local/`.

For some libraries, you should specify it with `./configure` like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/the/new/install/path
make
make install
```

Others allow you to specify it when `make install`:

```
./configure
make
make install prefix=/the/new/install/path
```

You can try both. At least one should resolve your issue.